# How to send information between 2 clients (Android)

Tags: android, ip, genymotion, backendless

What do I have?

- Backendless server code (backendless.com).
- Genymotion emulator with 2 virtual devices.

What do I want?

I want to send information between 2 virtual devices. I use Backendless server as intermediate server. It helps clients to connect to each other. When clients are connected, information is sent to the server bypass.

My problem.

When clients are connecting they must have different IP addresses, but for external servers 2 virtual devices have the same IPs.

How to set IPs for virtual devices so they have different IPs for external servers?

Sorry for my English, it's not my native language.

Answer (score 1):

Go to VirtualBox select a VM, click on settings button then:

- network left tab
- adapter1 tab
- Change "Attached to" to "Bridged Adapter"

Do the same manipulation for your second device.

Using the "Bridged Adapter" config make your network set a specific local IP  for each of your VMs.

Comment: VirtualBox displaying: No bridged network adapter is currently selected

Comment: Open "Advanced" settings on the network tab and select the adaptor you want to use.

Comment: I did it, but it gave me nothing